# Import wants >=0.6.0 but the import of the import is ^0.5.0

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, import

that solidity compiling is a mess :frowning:

I’m trying hours to find out why my contracts sometime compile and sometimes not …
Now I got it …

I'm using a local ganache server and the online IDE remix.ethereum.org

Want to compile that file:

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.12;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
```

And get this error:

```
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/GSN/Context.sol:1:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.6.12+commit.27d51765.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version pragma solidity ^0.5.0; ^---------------------^
```

When I look into the Context.sol (clicking in remix on the error popup):

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
```

At github (following the inport link) is it the version:

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.8.0;
```

Shouldn’t my import import the .sol from its own path? What is going on? Is it possible to “refresh” the compiled files in remix after deploying? - I guess thats the point, because I have another contract that use the older version.

Thanks hope for help :D

**EDIT**
Okay I found out that it doesn't happened when I use the remix with firefox instead of using it with chrome. There is also a libary "github" where openzeppelin is inside, with all the contracts that I import (only that one) but not at the local directory...

Answer (score 0):

The current openzeppelin contracts are using:

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.8.0;
```

... so I'm not too sure where

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
```

actually comes from. You can see here: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/GSN/Context.sol

... that is **not part of the same release as the rest of files you are using**. This could be a case of the `pragma` doing it's job and alerting you that something is wrong.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there a good tutorial you can recoment to learn? I just use diffrent tutorials to learn and I guess openzeppelin is just not that compatible with older version to do that.

Thank you sir.
I will start again from the scratch xD